# How to convert Either to MonadThrow

Tags: haskell, exception, types, monads, either

I have a function that handles errors via `Either`:

```
funErrViaEither :: a -> Either SomeException b
```

I want to use this function in another function that should be more flexible and return `MonadThrow m`:

```
funErrViaThrow :: MonadThrow m => a -> m b
funErrViaThrow x =
    if x = someCondition
        then funErrViaEither
        else throwM (SomeException MyCustomException)
```

This does not compile; the type checker complains that the return type of `funErrViaEither` does not match the expected type `m b`. I don't understand why - `Either` has an instance of `MonadThrow` with `SomeException` as the type of `Left`.

Where do I err? What would be the correct way to convert an error signalled via `Either` into one signalled via `MonadThrow`?

Comment: You can't do this in general. You're asking to convert a function which returns an `Either SomeException b` to one that can generically return *any* `m b` where `m` is an instance of `MonadThrow`. Your question is a bit like asking if you can convert an `Int` value into one of type `(Eq a) => a`, which you clearly can't in general. Perhaps your `funErrViaEither` can be rewritten to be able to take the more general type signature - but once you've given it the more specific signature, you can't use in a context that expects something more general.

Comment: Makes total sense, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can't use `funErrViaEither x :: Either SomeException b` directly as a general `MonadThrow m => m b`, you can process the `Either` using pattern matching, throwing or returning as appropriate:

```
case funErrViaEither x of
  Left err -> throwM err
  Right y -> return y
```

However, I think you've probably over-wrapped your exceptions with `SomeException`.  It's more likely that you want to peel this off when you switch from `Either SomeException` to `MonadThrow m`, so a full type-checked example would look like:

```
import Control.Monad.Catch

data MyCustomException = NoNegatives | NoOdds deriving (Show)
instance Exception MyCustomException

funErrViaEither :: Int -> Either SomeException Int
funErrViaEither n | n < 0     = throwM NoNegatives  -- or Left (SomeException NoNegatives)
                  | otherwise = Right $ n `div` 2

funErrViaThrow :: MonadThrow m => Int -> m Int
funErrViaThrow x =
    if even x
        then case funErrViaEither x of
               Left (SomeException err) -> throwM err  -- peel off SomeException
               Right y -> return y
        else throwM NoOdds

main = do
  print =<< funErrViaThrow 6
  (print =<< funErrViaThrow 5)
    `catch` (\err -> putStrLn $ "caught: " ++ show (err :: MyCustomException))
  print =<< funErrViaThrow (-2)
```